# can't display video in VideoView until I restart the app on android 12

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am making an app that records a video and then displays this video on another activity.

the problem is that this video cannot be played right away, i would have to record the video, and then restart the android app for it to show. otherwise it shows me a message that
says: "can't play this video".

Moreover the thing that i really dont understand is that i tried it on an older phone of android version 11 and it works perfectly, but for some reason on the new phone it doesn't

i have made some research and i think it has something to do with the storage permissions but i am not sure since i tried fixing it with no luck.

what can i do to fix this?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
CameraManager CamMan;

boolean flag = false;

public static boolean FirstDirectoryCreated;

CameraSource cameraSource;

Button seeVideos;

public static File LeakedVids;

public static boolean isDirectoryCreated;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
    }

    seeVideos = findViewById(R.id.seeVideos);


        init();

        createFiles();

    CamMan = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    seeVideos.setOnClickListener(v -> goToVideos());

}


    private void goToVideos() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowVideo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(a);
}


    private void createFiles () {

        File EyeTracker = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "Eye Tracker");
        FirstDirectoryCreated = EyeTracker.exists() || EyeTracker.mkdirs();

        if (FirstDirectoryCreated) {


            LeakedVids = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator
                    + "Eye Tracker", "Leaked Videos");
            isDirectoryCreated = LeakedVids.exists() || LeakedVids.mkdirs();

        }
    }


    private void init () {
        flag = true;

        initCameraSource();
    }

    //method to create camera source from faceFactoryDaemon class
    private void initCameraSource () {
        FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(this)
                .setTrackingEnabled(true)
                .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .setMode(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE)
                .build();
        detector.setProcessor(new MultiProcessor.Builder(new FaceTrackerDaemon(MainActivity.this)).build());

        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, detector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1024, 768)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
                .build();
        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
                return;
            }
            cameraSource.start();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume () {
        super.onResume();
        if (cameraSource != null) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
                    return;
                }
                cameraSource.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause () {
        super.onPause();
        if (cameraSource != null) {
            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (cameraSource != null) {
            cameraSource.release();
        }
    }

    //update view
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void updateMainView (Condition condition){
        switch (condition) {
            case USER_EYES_OPEN:
                openCam();
                break;
            case FACE_NOT_FOUND:
                break;
        }
    }
    public void openCam () {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoPreview.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }

}
```

VideoPreview

```
public class VideoPreview extends AppCompatActivity {

private VideoCapture<Recorder> videoCapture = null;
private Recording recording = null;

private ExecutorService cameraExecutor;

private ActivityVideoPreviewBinding viewBinding;


Timer timer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_preview);
    viewBinding = ActivityVideoPreviewBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(viewBinding.getRoot());


    startCamera();


    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            captureVideo();
        }
    }, 173);


    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopRec();
        }
    }, 6000);

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            backToMain();
        }
    }, 6100);



    cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}

private void stopRec() {
    Recording curRecording = recording;
    if (curRecording != null) {
        // Stop the current recording session.
        curRecording.stop();
        recording = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ntek Ntor Ya Zabre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void captureVideo() {


   /* MediaStoreOutputOptions mediaStoreOutputOptions = (new androidx.camera.video.MediaStoreOutputOptions
            .Builder(this.getContentResolver(), android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI))
            .build(); */

            String name = "LeakedVideo_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
            File vids = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator
                    + "Eye Tracker" + File.separator + "Leaked Videos", name);


            FileOutputOptions fileOutputOptions = new FileOutputOptions.Builder(vids).build();

            if (videoCapture != null) {
                PendingRecording recording = (videoCapture.getOutput())
                        .prepareRecording(this, fileOutputOptions);
                this.recording = recording.start((ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)), videoRecordEvent -> {


                });
            }
        }



private void startCamera() {


    ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener((() -> {
        ProcessCameraProvider var10000 = null;
        try {
            var10000 = cameraProviderFuture.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert var10000 != null;
        Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue(var10000, "cameraProviderFuture.get()");
        ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = var10000;

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();


        preview.setSurfaceProvider(viewBinding.viewFinder.getSurfaceProvider());

        Recorder recorder = (new Recorder.Builder())
                .setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.HIGHEST))
                .build();
        videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder);


        CameraSelector cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA;


        try {
            cameraProvider.unbindAll();

            cameraProvider
                    .bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, videoCapture);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Log.e("CameraXApp", "Use case binding failed", exc);
        }

    }), ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
}


protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    cameraExecutor.shutdown();
}

public void backToMain() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

ShowVideo:

```
public class ShowVideo extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private CardStackLayoutManager manager;

public static File[] files;
public static List<Video> videos;

public static int num;

File newFile;

String dir;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_video);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }

            dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getPath();

            files = MainActivity.LeakedVids.listFiles();



        num = 1;
        videos = new ArrayList<>();
        CardStackView cardStackView = findViewById(R.id.card_stack_view);

        if (files.length > 0) {
            videos.add(new Video(files[files.length - 1].getPath()));
            Adapter adapter = new Adapter(videos);
            cardStackView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Videos to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        manager = new CardStackLayoutManager(this, new CardStackListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCardDragging(Direction direction, float ratio) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onCardSwiped: p=" + manager.getTopPosition() + " d=" + direction);
                if (direction == Direction.Right) {

                    if (files.length == 1) {
                        newFile = new File(dir, files[files.length - 1].getName());
                        FileChannel outputChannel = null;
                        FileChannel inputChannel = null;
                        try {
                            outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel();
                            inputChannel = new FileInputStream(files[files.length - 1]).getChannel();
                            inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
                            inputChannel.close();
                            files[files.length - 1].delete();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            if (inputChannel != null) {
                                try {
                                    inputChannel.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            if (outputChannel != null) {
                                try {
                                    outputChannel.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {

                        newFile = new File(dir, files[files.length - num].getName());
                        FileChannel outputChannel = null;
                        FileChannel inputChannel = null;
                        try {
                            outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel();
                            inputChannel = new FileInputStream(files[files.length - num]).getChannel();
                            inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
                            inputChannel.close();
                            files[files.length - num].delete();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            if (inputChannel != null) {
                                try {
                                    inputChannel.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            if (outputChannel != null) {
                                try {
                                    outputChannel.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (direction == Direction.Left) {
                    if (files.length == 1) {
                        files[files.length - 1].delete();
                    } else {

                        files[files.length - num].delete();
                    }
                }

                if (files != null) {
                    if (files.length > num) {
                        num++;
                        videos.add(new Video(files[files.length - num].getPath()));
                    }
                }
                Adapter adapter = new Adapter(videos);
                cardStackView.setAdapter(adapter);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCardRewound() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCardRewound: " + manager.getTopPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCardCanceled() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCardRewound: " + manager.getTopPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCardAppeared(View view, int position) {


            }


            @Override
            public void onCardDisappeared(View view, int position) {


            }
        });
        manager.setStackFrom(StackFrom.None);
        manager.setVisibleCount(3);
        manager.setTranslationInterval(8.0f);
        manager.setScaleInterval(0.95f);
        manager.setSwipeThreshold(0.3f);
        manager.setMaxDegree(20.0f);
        manager.setDirections(Direction.FREEDOM);
        manager.setCanScrollHorizontal(true);
        manager.setCanScrollVertical(false);
        manager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.Manual);
        manager.setOverlayInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        cardStackView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        cardStackView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent a = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(a);
}
```

}

Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Video> videos;


public Adapter(List<Video> videos) {
    this.videos = videos;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int position) {
    //LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);


     return new ViewHolder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(videos.get(position));

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("param", videos.get(position).getPath());
        holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return videos.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public static VideoView videoView;

    ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        videoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_video);
    }

    void setData(Video video) {
            videoView.setVideoPath(video.getPath());

            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer::start);

            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer::start);

    }


}





public List<Video> getItems() {
    return videos;
}

public void setItems(List<Video> items) {
    this.videos = items;
}
```

}

the problem is that when i open the 'ShowVideo' class the video doesnt play until i restart the app

pls help.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: right away _JoeyElHajj